# troubleshoot nautilus thumbnails on SMB share

Tags: gnome, nautilus, thumbnails

I need some help understanding how the thumbnail process works with Gnome Nautilus. I am running Gnome 43.2 with nautilus 43.1 on Manjaro Linux.

Other computers show file thumbnails just fine on my home server (debian) shares. This one - a recent install - does not. Thumbnails are generated OK locally, the dconf `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/show-image-thumbnails` is set to `always`.

Now the most interesting and annoying thing. If I open the folder with `gThumb` viewer - that generates thumbnails AND the thumbnails can be also seen in nautilus (albeit they are smaller than the standard ones created by nautilus locally.

I tried to execute `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` in a terminal window that is opened on that share - that works and it can create the output file. Presumably something is wrong with the particular thumbnailer executed by nautilus, but how to find which it is and how it works?

By the way - I installed thunar too - and it does NOT generate thumbnails either locally or on the smb share.

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this problem?

Comment: It solved itself after several updates. It is a bit annoying as another laptop same environment same OS did not have this glitch. All I can say - from time to tome delete failed thumbnails and recheck. How recent was your installation?

Comment: For me it ultimately was just a matter of enabling thumbnails on remote mountpoints, so not relevant to your problem afaict.

Comment: Thanks, you mean to set "show image thumbnails" to "always" in nautilus interface, right?

Comment: Yes indeed! It was set to "local files only" or something like that, but since we use SMB mounts and store pictures on those mounts, we want to be able to see those thumbnails as well, hence the need to change this.